# Distinct/Aggregation query Mongodb array, trim trailing space

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I have a MongoDB collection which contains a colours array like :

myCollection :

```
{
_id : ...,
"colours" : [ 
    {
        "colourpercentage" : "42",
        "colourname" : "Blue"
    }, 
    {
        "colourpercentage" : "32",
        "colourname" : "Red"
    }, 
    {
        "colourpercentage" : "10",
        "colourname" : "Green "
    }
  ]
}
```

I would like to retrieve every distinct colourname of every entry of this collection, and be able to filter it with a search.

I tried with distinct but without success. I searched further and found that an aggregation could help me. For the moment I have :

```
db.getCollection('myCollection').aggregate([
    { "$match": { "colours.colourname": /Gre/ } }, # Gre is my search
    { "$unwind": "$colours" },
    { "$match": { "colours.colourname": /search/ } },
    { "$group": {
       "_id": "$colours.colourname"
    }}
])
```

It is working, but I get an array like :

```
{
"result" : [ 
    {
        "_id" : "Grey"
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : "Light Green "
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : "Light Green"
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : "Green "
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : "Green"
    }
],
"ok" : 1.0000000000000000
}
```

And I would like to remove duplicate entries which have a space in the end and displays them like :

```
["Grey","Light Green","Green"]
```

Comment: You're probably best off cleaning up your docs to remove any trailing spaces in your `colourname` fields rather than trying to remove it during the aggregation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach you could take is the **[Map-Reduce](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/map-reduce/)** way even though the JavaScript interpreter driven **[mapReduce](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/mapReduce)** takes a bit longer than the aggregation framework but will work since you will be using some very useful native JavaScript functions that are lacking in the aggregation framework. For instance, in the map function you could use the [**`trim()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim) function to remove any trailing spaces in your `colourname` fields so that you can emit the "cleansed" keys.

The Map-Reduce operation would typically have the following map and reduce functions:

```
var map = function() {
    if (!this.colours) return;
    this.colours.forEach(function (c){
        emit(c.colourname.trim(), 1)
    });
};

var reduce = function(key, values) {
    var count = 0;
    for (index in values) {
        count += values[index];
    }
    return count;    
};

db.runCommand( { mapreduce : "myCollection", map : map , reduce : reduce , out : "map_reduce_result" } );
```

You can then query `map_reduce_result` collection with the regex to have the result:

```
var getDistinctKeys = function (doc) { return doc._id };
var result = db.map_reduce_result.find({ "_id": /Gre/ }).map(getDistinctKeys);
print(result); // prints ["Green", "Grey", "Light Green"]
```

---

-- **UPDATE** --

To implement this in Python, PyMongo's **[API](http://api.mongodb.org/python/2.0/examples/map_reduce.html)** supports all of the features of MongoDB’s map/reduce engine thus you could try the following:

```
import pymongo
import re
from bson.code import Code

client = pymongo.MongoClient("localhost", 27017)
db = client.test
map = Code("function () {"
            "   if (!this.colours) return;"
            "   this.colours.forEach(function (c){"
            "       emit(c.colourname.trim(), 1)"
            "   });"
            "};")

reduce = Code("function (key, values) {"
            "   var count = 0;"
            "       for (index in values) {"
            "           count += values[index];"
            "       }"
            "       return count;"    
            "   };")

result = db.myCollection.map_reduce(map, reduce, "map_reduce_result")
regx = re.compile("Gre", re.IGNORECASE)

for doc in result.find({"_id": regx}):
    print(doc)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am working with Python and PyMongo 2.8. I tried to implement your solution and am struggling. Any idea with this language ? I used this to translate : http://api.mongodb.org/python/2.0/examples/map_reduce.html

Comment: @Kiruchi You were in the right direction though, I have updated my answer to include an example of how you would go about that with pymongo.

Comment: I can't thank you enough. Thank you for your patience, your kindness and what you taught me. I actually struggled on the map_reduce line, but it is working like a charm right now. Thanks again !

Comment: @Kiruchi No worries :-) Glad it all worked out for you in the end.